# Eliminar elementos de un vector usando iteradores: resultado inesperado

Tags: c++

La consigna es la siguiente:

> **a)** Escriba un función genérica del_maxmin que reciba un vector de elementos del tipo genérico y elimine del mismo tanto el máximo elemento como el mínimo. Si alguno de estos valores a eliminar está repetido, debe eliminarlo todas las veces que aparezca.
>
> **b)** Implemente además
> un programa cliente que genere dos vectores, uno de enteros y otro de strings, y pruebe la función con ambos, mostrando en pantalla los vectores antes y después de invocar a la función.

Y lo que planteé fue esto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void del_maxmin(vector<T> &v) {

    vector<int>::iterator it_max;
    vector<int>::iterator it_min;
    for(int i = 0; i<v.size(); i++) {
        it_max = max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
        it_min = min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    }
    
    v.erase(v.begin() + *it_max);
    v.erase(v.begin() + *it_min);
    
    for(int i = 0; i<v.size(); i++) {
        if(v[i] == *it_max || v[i] == *it_min) {
            v.erase(v.begin() + v[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    vector<int>v1(10);
    for(size_t i = 0; i<v1.size(); i++) {
        v1[i] = rand() % 20 + 1;
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i<v1.size(); i++) {
        cout << v1[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl; 
    
    del_maxmin(v1);
    for(size_t i = 0; i<v1.size(); i++) {
        cout << v1[i] << " ";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Cuando ejecuto mi programa, me devuelve un código de salida:

El código de salida es este: 3221225477

¿Me podrían decir cuál es el error en mi planteo?

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A grandes rasgos, un iterador es equivalente a un puntero. En concreto, el tipo `iterator` definido dentro de `std::vector< >` cumple con los requisitos de un [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).

Para simplificar, asumamos que lo de *equivalente a un vector* es literalmente cierto.

```
for(int i = 0; i<v.size(); i++) {
    it_max = max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    it_min = min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

Ese código no tiene ningún sentido. Obtienes un puntero al elemento mayor o menor, tantas veces como tamaño tenga el vector.

```
v.erase(v.begin() + *it_max);
v.erase(v.begin() + *it_min);
```

Esto ya no es solo que no tenga sentido, es que además incurres en comportamiento indefinido. Eliminas un elemento situado en la posición almacenada en el índice `it_max` o `it_min`. Y, según tu código, los vectores contienen valores numéricos aleatorios.

```
if(v[i] == *it_max || v[i] == *it_min) {
    v.erase(v.begin() + v[i]);
}
```

Otro comportamiento indefinido: `v[i]` contiene un valor aleatorio, por lo que `v.begin( ) + v[i]` implica que accedes a una posición de memoria aleatoria.

Otra cosa:

```
vector<int>::iterator it_max;
vector<int>::iterator it_min;
```

Tu código compila porque estás usando exclusivamente `std::vector< int >`. Estas forzando el tipo, con lo que tu función deja de ser genérica y está limitada a tipos compatibles con `int`.

Y por último, y el mayor problema de tu código ([fuente: cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)):

> The use of erase( iter ) invalidates iterators and references **AT OF AFTER** the point of the erase.

Que, en traducción libre por mi parte:

> El uso de `erase( iter )` invalida todos los iteradores que referencien **A O DESPUÉS** del elemento eliminado.

Eso quiere decir que, si haces `erase( ITER )`, **no puedes seguir usando ese iterador**, puesto ha quedado invalidado por la operación de eliminar.

Tu código corregido quedaría:

```
template< typename T > void del_maxmin( vector< T > &v ) {
    T it_max = *max_element( v.begin( ), v.end( ) );
    T it_min = *min_element( v.begin( ), v.end( ) );

    for( vector< T >::iterator iter = v.begin( ); iter != v.end( ); ++iter ) {
        if( ( *iter == it_max ) || ( *iter == it_min ) ) {
            v.erase( iter );
            iter = v.begin( );
        }
    }
}
```

Observa que ese código es muy poco eficiente, puesto que cada vez que eliminas un elemento hay que volver a empezar **desde el principio**. Una posible mejora sería, por ejemplo, guardar un iterador al elemento **anterior** al eliminado.

Comment: `vector.erase()` te devuelve un iterador válido a la siguiente posición. No es necesario empezar desde el principio cada vez que borras cualquier elemento. Simplemente basta con quitar el `++iter` incondicional del `for` y hacerlo únicamente cuando no se llame a `erase` (con un `if-else`). Es como si `erase` hiciese el incremento por ti

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de [@Juanjo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/405599/463) fuerza a empezar de 0 cada vez que se elimina un elemento. Esto no es para nada necesario puesto que la función `erase` ya nos devuelve un iterador válido que apunta al siguiente elemento del vector. Lo que tenemos que hacer entonces es incrementar el iterador únicamente cuando no haya que borrar elementos del vector:

```
template< typename T > void del_maxmin( vector< T > &v ) {
    T it_max = *max_element( v.begin( ), v.end( ) );
    T it_min = *min_element( v.begin( ), v.end( ) );

    for( vector< T >::iterator iter = v.begin( ); iter != v.end( ); ) // <<--- Se elimina el incremento incondicional
    {
        if( ( *iter == it_max ) || ( *iter == it_min ) ) {
            iter = v.erase( iter ); // Recuperamos el iterador válido
        }
        else
        {
            ++iter;  // Avanzamos a la siguiente posición
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Un tanto más eficiente, usando el "erase-remove" idiom:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
void del_maxmin(std::vector<T>& v)
{
    auto val = *std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), val), v.end()); // Erase–remove idiom
    
    val = *std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), val), v.end());
}

template<typename T>
void mostrar(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    for (const auto& i : v)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 10, 20, 30, 30, 35, 40, 40, 10, 15, 40 };
    
    mostrar(v);
    del_maxmin(v);
    mostrar(v);
    
    std::vector<std::string> vs{ "La", "luna", "vino", "a",
        "la", "fragua", "con", "su", "polisón", "de", "nardos.", 
        "El", "niño", "la", "mira", "mira.", 
        "El", "niño", "la", "está", "mirando" };
    
    mostrar(vs);
    del_maxmin(vs);
    mostrar(vs);
}
```